# How to make eclipse editor Normal

Tags: eclipse

I don't know what change I made to my eclipse some of the files is having some weird boxes and green color background as posted in the image.[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting it? It should reset to your default afterwards. If you accidentally changed the default, try going into the View menu in the Preferences and looking around for possible related options (sorry, don't have Eclipse on my current computer and can't remember the exact titles).

Comment: Exactly which download of Eclipse is this? Have you added any plugins to it afterward?

Comment: I am using Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) . I did not install any plugins all I remember is i messed up with some preferences option.is there any way to reset back to previous settings.